# how to select span based on @id of sibling input

Tags: selenium, testing, xpath

I have the label below, this is a label for multiple select option buttons, each select have its on div inside there is a label and then inside that label there is an ID that I need to use to determine which one I want selenium to click.

```
<label class="custom-toggle-checkbox-label">
   <input type="checkbox" class="custom-toggle-checkbox-input" id="selectOption_1_Value" 
   value="false">
<span class="custom-toggle-checkbox-slider"></span>
</label>


<label class="custom-toggle-checkbox-label">
       <input type="checkbox" class="custom-toggle-checkbox-input" id="selectOption_2_Value" 
       value="false">
    <span class="custom-toggle-checkbox-slider"></span>
    </label>
.....
```

I simply tried but the element is not interactable on this point. I will need to click on the span element in order to select it which is under the label element

```
xpath = //*[@id='selectOption_1_Value']
```

I also tried to use the full xpath of the element but there are multiple labels with the same class name and I would like to avoid using full xpath locators.

My question is how can select the correct label based on its children ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to select `span` based on `@id` of sibling `input` try

```
//label[input[@id='selectOption_1_Value']]/span
```

or

```
//input[@id='selectOption_1_Value']/following-sibling::span
```

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what i was looking for, also changed the title of the question to reflect exactly what you described :)